# Send ' symbol through mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a php code

```
$Txt=$_POST['chat_txt'];
$Txt=trim($Txt);
$Txt=htmlspecialchars($Txt);
$Txt=preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $Txt);
$ins=$con->query("INSERT INTO chat (Message,From_) VALUES('$Txt','$NameId')");
```

And if `$Txt` is `We're` then it is going to return  an error about right to use syntax.What do i have to do to prevent that?

Comment: Use prepared statements to get MySQL to escape strings correctly.

Comment: @apokryfos aren't there any other way?

Comment: use `mysql_real_escape_string` or `addslashes`, can be a start.

Comment: addslashes can be a replacement for your preg_replace, in this case.

Comment: Well, there's countless other ways. However prepared statements is the most reliable one.

Comment: @apokryfos what about addslashes?

Comment: @J.Doe addslashes doesn't deal with the DB encoding, just the PHP-side encoding. It would probably be fine if everything is in Unicode.

Comment: @apokryfos well it worked for me